# Add a global search form on all my views with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I have a controller with a method that returns a form.

```
public function showFormAction()
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('search', 'search')
        ->getForm()
    ;

    return $this->render('???', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

What must I do to make it visible on all my views?

Comment: is that form will be used in many pages ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can embed the result of another controller in any view with the tag:

```
{{ render(controller("AcmeFormBundle:Form:search")) }}
```

For more details see http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers